# Windows batch file: move files older than X minutes to a different directory using UnixUtils find command

Tags: windows, unix

I found the unixutils for Windows and am trying to use the find command to move files older than 30 minutes to a different directory.

I have tried all of the following (also with \ at the end of SourceDir and/or TargetDir) but get various errors that I'm pretty sure are due to unix using / to delimit directories and Windows using \ to delimit directories:

```
find C:\SourceDir -name * -mmin +30 -type f -exec "move {} C:\TargetDir" ;
find C:\SourceDir -name * -mmin +30 -type f -exec "move {} C:\TargetDir" +
find C:\SourceDir -name * -mmin +30 -type f -execdir "move {} C:\TargetDir" ;
find C:\SourceDir -name * -mmin +30 -type f -execdir "move {} C:\TargetDir" +
```

Has anybody got this to work?

I'm also not tied to using this utility - it just seemed like it would be easy to do.  I do have to do it via command line, though, as part of a scheduled job, and would very much prefer not to have to install any software.  Copying standalone single file utilities is acceptable, though.

I believe Windows Powershell is available to me, as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found somebody who helped me with Windows Powershell.  I thought I'd provide an update here in case it helps somebody else later.

The following Powershell command does the same thing:

```
get-childitem -Path "C:\SourceDir" -recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -le (get-date).AddMinutes(-30)} | move-item -destination "C:\TargetDir" -force
```